# Solr Service is getting down while indexing files of size more than 1Gb

Tags: solr, solrj

In Apache Solr, how to index files of size more than 1 gb in solr espically CSV files?
Solr service is going down when after indexing 250 MB of data getting heap memory exception.But depending on file size i can't increase heap memory. Is there any solution to handle these issues?
Solr Version - 5.1
Solr heap memory - 5 gb

Thanks In advance

Comment: There are only two choices for dealing with OOME. One is to increase the size of the Java heap, the other is to reduce the amount of memory that Solr needs.

Comment: Any reason why you can't index the file in multiple batches?

Comment: Thanks Oyeme,MatsLindh for quick response, I tried passing 50 mb of data to solr using atomic update but after 16 iterations solr service is going down.